# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype'). Next.Js and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

I'm trying to use express in next js, but errors appears when I try to instantiate express:

```
  const express = require('express');
```

Errors:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\<user>\<project>\node_modules\on-finished'

Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\Users\<user>\<project>\node_modules\raw-body'
```

Edit notes:

I've already tried `npm i`

I'm using node 4.19.0 and express 4.18.2.

when I run `npm install -g npm@latest`, it says the operation is not permitted.

Comment: Can you let us know what version of Node and Express you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest nodejs and npm version or you can run the below command

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: this gives me an error saying that the operation is not permitted

Comment: Then you have to allow permission for npm based on your OS.